# How i can delete text inside li with jquery or regular javascript, wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, html-lists

I want to delete text "previous" inside li in wordpress theme.
[the text to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne2b5.png)

```
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
 <li class="flex-nav-prev">
   <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
 </li>

 <li class="flex-nav-next">
   <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with jquery like this :

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

$('li.flex-nav-prev').html('');

```js
$('li.flex-nav-prev').html('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
       <li class="flex-nav-prev">
         <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
       </li>

       <li class="flex-nav-next">
         <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

It's works in snippet but it doesn't work on website.
Thank you so much

Comment: try $('li.flex-nav-prev > a').html('')

Comment: show your full code. it should work

Comment: Images of code are not allowed - please edit your question to include the code in your question as a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To delete just the text of an element try this jquery code:

```
jQuery('flex-nav-prev > a').contents().filter(function(){
      return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```